# PowerShell change console tab size

Tags: powershell, console, powershell-5.0

Let's say I have a file called `test.txt` with a tab and some text. I `cat` the file and on my Windows 10 1511 installation the tab is displayed as 8 spaces. Say I want to change it to 4.

How do I change how many spaces the PowerShell console displays a tab as? A solution that is written in PowerShell and can be added to a profile script would be preferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the tab length in cmd.exe](http://superuser.com/questions/425122/set-the-tab-length-in-cmd-exe)

Comment: @DavidPostill I disagree. Since this if specifically for PowerShell, a PowerShell script/code to change the tab size would be the intended solution. I've edited my question to clarify this. Also, the accepted solution resolves the problem for Mercurial `hg diff` from what I understand.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in PowerShell